# Pentaho DI 8.0 JDBC file location

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I recently installed PDI 8.0 and do not see the usual JDBC file structure where the database driver jars are saved (pentaho/design-tools/data-integration/lib).

Below is what was extracted out, note I tried dropping the jar into Data Integration.app, as well as recreating the structure from prior versions and re-starting PDI but no success as of yet.

So my question is: where do the JDBC jar files go now in PDI 8.0?

```
douglas@localhost:~/pentaho$ ls -lth
total 11M
drwxr-xr-x  2 douglas douglas 4.0K Feb 18 12:51 logs
drwxr-xr-x  3 douglas douglas 4.0K Feb 18 12:34 design-tools
drwxr-xr-x  3 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:49 Data Integration.app
drwxr-xr-x  4 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:49 adaptive-execution
drwxr-xr-x  2 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:49 Data Service JDBC Driver
drwxr-xr-x 28 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:49 plugins
drwxr-xr-x  6 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:49 libswt
drwxr-xr-x  2 douglas douglas  20K Nov  5 16:49 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.5K Nov  5 16:47 Carte.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.3K Nov  5 16:47 carte.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:47 classes
drwxr-xr-x  3 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:47 docs
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.1K Nov  5 16:47 Encr.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.1K Nov  5 16:47 encr.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.1K Nov  5 16:47 Import.bat
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 2.3K Nov  5 16:47 import-rules.xml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.2K Nov  5 16:47 import.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.1K Nov  5 16:47 Kitchen.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.3K Nov  5 16:47 kitchen.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:47 launcher
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas  14K Nov  5 16:47 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.1K Nov  5 16:47 Pan.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.2K Nov  5 16:47 pan.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.2K Nov  5 16:47 purge-utility.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.3K Nov  5 16:47 purge-utility.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:47 pwd
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.3K Nov  5 16:47 README.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.5K Nov  5 16:47 runSamples.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.2K Nov  5 16:47 runSamples.sh
drwxr-xr-x  5 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:47 samples
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 5.0K Nov  5 16:47 set-pentaho-env.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 4.5K Nov  5 16:47 set-pentaho-env.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:47 simple-jndi
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.2K Nov  5 16:47 Spark-app-builder.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.2K Nov  5 16:47 spark-app-builder.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 4.7K Nov  5 16:47 Spoon.bat
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas  220 Nov  5 16:47 spoon.command
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 1.1K Nov  5 16:47 SpoonConsole.bat
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 2.2K Nov  5 16:47 SpoonDebug.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.9K Nov  5 16:47 SpoonDebug.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas 362K Nov  5 16:47 spoon.ico
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas  745 Nov  5 16:47 spoon.png
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 7.1K Nov  5 16:47 spoon.sh
drwxr-xr-x  5 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:47 system
drwxr-xr-x  3 douglas douglas 4.0K Nov  5 16:47 ui
-rwxr-xr-x  1 douglas douglas 1.7K Nov  5 16:47 yarn.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 douglas douglas  11M Nov  5 14:13 PentahoDataIntegration_OSS_Licenses.html
```

Comment: what's in the lib directory ? Try this command to find jar files in that directory : find . -name '*.jar'

Comment: @EugèneAdell You were spot on, I thought this was for some other component but once I moved it there and restarted the database connection test passed. If you post as the answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the lib directory, and if not found at this place, run this command to find all jar files : `find . -name '*.jar'`